# Gnome 3.32.0 Super+n keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome-shell

This problem seems to come and go with different Gnome releases but it's definitely back in Gnome 3.32.0. I have a custom shortcut that uses Super+1 (Emacs) but it instead launches Firefox. On another system "Launch web browser" is set to Super+2 but instead it launches nautilus file manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MR 370](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/merge_requests/370), by popular demand the <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>(number)</kbd> shortcuts now activate the first 9 **pinned applications** from the 'dock'. This mirrors the behavior in Ubuntu Unity and Windows 7–10.

The problem of newly added standard actions overriding custom shortcuts is tracked in [issue 1093](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1093), and in the mean time you can use `dconf-editor org.gnome.shell.keybindings` to remove the "switch-to-application-x" hotkeys.

Comment: This is actually better. I can delete all my custom shortcuts and arrange my pinned applications the way I want the shortcuts.

Comment: Many thanks. I assumed something like this, but could not find the settings.